# Java's BlockingQueue Take Policy

Tags: java, multithreading, policy, blockingqueue, take

In a multithreaded environment, what is the policy regarding the `take()` method (removing an Object) for the various implementations of Java's `BlockingQueue` (for example `LinkedBlockingQueue`)?

Does the thread that calls `take()` first get the first available Object, e.g. is it a first come, first served, random, or is there some other policy describing how the queue is accessed by multiple threads? I cannot seem to find anything in the docs.

Comment: What "policy" are you looking for?  Do you mean multiple threads blocked on a single `take()` method?

Comment: Yes. `BlockingQueue` follows `first-in-first-out` and is `thread-safe`
Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take()

Comment: Updated with a better explanation.

Comment: LinkedBlockingQueue is not fair.  ArrayBlockingQueue has a constructor with a fairness parameter.  I don't know about any other ones.  It's a pretty rare requirement -- are you sure you need it?

Comment: @MattTimmermans [`SynchronousQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) also supports optional fairness policy.

Comment: When they mean thread safe, it means the thread that was able to access the queue is the one that gets the lock. So it’s a first come first serve basis

Comment: @MattTimmermans it would be helpful to know it, for statistic purposes.